# Maven alternate settings.xml when don't have option of mvn -s

Tags: bash, maven

We're working with an integration partner who's given us a set of bash scripts, which then call Maven projects/targets.  I'm trying to let our (shared) Jenkins server build those projects.  In Maven2, one could provide a org.apache.maven.user-settings MAVEN_OPT setting.  Maven3 no longer supports that [option](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5026).

*Things I've tried:*

1. the afore-mentioned org.apache.maven.user-settings
2. alias mvn='mvn -s /path/to/project-settings.xml'

*Things I've considered, but haven't yet tried:*

- Writing a wrapping [mvn exec](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html), so I can execute my job from within Jenkins and provide an alternate settings file via its means

I've seen threads where others have wrestled with this, but haven't yet seen a proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included enough details for me to be *sure* that this is answering your question (*why* do you need 2 settings.xmls?), but I think this will work for most needs:

You can use a [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles) element in the settings.xml. Just activate the one you need for the project you're working with.

---

Alternatively, [as seen here](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-3-support-for-org-apache-maven-user-settings-td3261146.html):

> Instead of placing the settings.xml and repository in the service account's home, we keep it with the rest of our build configuration.

**Probably not a good idea**, but it's an option.

Comment: We've got multiple projects out on Jenkins, so have tried to segment them into separate settings.xml files, yeah, loosely kept with the rest of our build configuration.  That then lets us use them as developers on our boxes, as well.  Keeps us from sharing URLs and credentials for repositories.

Comment: @TinaC OK why isn't this answer a solution to that problem?  Have one master settings.xml with different parts activated depending on the project.